# JXL library call

Tags: java, jxl

i am a barely new to the java (was always on c# before) and need to create a swing application where i need to read a data from xls file. So i use jXL.

I have a class, which returns name of a first sheet from excel file, choosen in jFileChooser. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

public class ExcelObject
{
    private String filename = null;
    private Workbook wb = null;
    private Sheet sheet = null;

    public ExcelObject(String f) 
    {
        filename = f;
    }

    public String getSheetName()
    {
        String sheet_name = null;

        try
        {
            wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(filename));
            sheet = wb.getSheet(0);
            sheet_name = sheet.getName();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            wb.close();
        }

        return sheet_name;
    }

}
```

in the program call looks like :

```
ExcelObject ex = new ExcelObject(filename);
String s = ex.getSheetName();
lblReport.setText(s);
```

So the issue is : when ran in the eclipse (3.4.2) i am getting a correct value, when jar is compiled, **NO VALUE IS RETURNED**! I mean lblReport is empty, with no exceptions and warnings.

Keep in mind : all other external jars work fine.

I tried a lot of things but none is working.

Also, if i do something like

```
                            ExcelObject ex = new ExcelObject(filename);
                            String s = ex.getSheetName();
//                          lblReportRun.setText(s);

                            lblReportRun.setText("Test");
                            lblAnyOtherLabel.setText("Test");
```

no text is displayed in the labels either, in compiled jar, and fine in eclipse.

Comment: Where is the excel file in relation to your code? Are you using a fully qualified filename?

Comment: Yes, i am getting it thru JFileChooser :

Comment: Cannot insert the code here...

Comment: JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);chooser.setFileFilter(new xlsFilter());int state = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);      File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            if(file != null && state == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)            {             String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();             txtFilePath.setText(filename);             ExcelObject ex = new ExcelObject(filename);
             String s = ex.getSheetName();

Comment: sorry for this ugly format...

Comment: so its getAbsolutePath(); to get a full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because if some exception occurs when opening the workbook, you catch it, print the stack trace, and then close the workbook in the finally block. But since an exception occurred when calling `Workbook.getWorkbook`, the `wb` variable is still null, and you're trying to invoke `close` on it. So a `NullPointerException` happens while in the finally block.

Watch your console, you must have some exception popping up.

Also, note that fileName should be the only instance variable of your class, that Java variable normally don't contain underscores and use camelCase, and thet the fileName variable should be of type File, rather than String : you get a File from the file chooser, transform it into a string, and then transform it back to a File.

Another possibility, since it works in Eclipse and not when run externally, is that you forgot to put the jXL jar in the classpath, which causes some ClassNotFoundException when trying to use the ExcelObject class.

Comment: No, no, no, again : in eclipse there are no exceptions/warnings etc ever! ALWAYS i get the correct value from ANY excel file i choose. But, when jar is compiled, lables are empty.

Comment: See my edited answer. Even if the first explanation is not the good one for this problem, it might cause problems later. You'd better fix the code.

Comment: Let me try the File option. But its obviously not the classpath paroblem (eclipse would not give you to compile the jar!)

Comment: You said you didn't run the app from Eclipse. The jar that Eclipse compiles contains your classes, and not the classes from jXL. You need your jar and the jXL jar in the classpath when you run the application.

Comment: oooohhhh can you please tell me how exactly do that??? is it standart jar compilation or something else?

Comment: btw, all the classes are included same way so why only jXL does not work??? i have itext and ojdbc5 which are fine...

Comment: Run your application with java -cp MyJar.jar;jXL.jar com.foo.bar.Main (assuming you're on windows. If on Linux or Mac, replace ; with :) Tell us if your jar is an executable jar or not, where all the jars are, and which command you run to execute your program.

Comment: is there any way to do it from eclipse?

Comment: You won't start Eclipse each time you want to run your application, will you? And you won't distribute Eclipse with your application just to be able to run it, will you?

Comment: ok what i always did is went Export->JAR file etc ... after all i ran jar from whatever folder i saved it to

Comment: And how do you run this jar, from outside Eclipse?

Comment: as i just said - double click on jar in the folder where it was compiled, did i do something wrong???

Comment: You never mentioned double-clicking before. If you want to be able to double-click on the jar, then the jar must be an executable jar, and its manifest file must contain a Main-Class entry, referencing the relative location of all the jars that must be in the classpath. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/. It's possible to do it with Eclipse, but it's not very intuitive. Learn what the jar file must contain and where the other jars must be. Or just launch it with java -cp ... as I told you before.

Comment: well i mentioned that i am from .NET that means when the code is working in IDE, you click F5 and go to folder where .exe is and double click on it to execute)))) sorry, if i missed something ... but is here a process of compilation is different? And what Export-> JAR file does in this case???

Comment: A jar is just a library. As a DLL. It's not necessarily executable. And even if it is, it still relies on other libraries that must be present along the executable jar file. Read the tutorial I linked to. It explains it all.

Comment: so i need a "hard linkage" in this case (where all the external sources incluided in the exec file), is it what you talking about? because eventually i will need to distrtibute the jar to other people and have them use it

Comment: You can do that, or distribute your jar file along with the jar it depends on. Read the the tutorial I linked to. It explains it all.